# Create numeric range slicer

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a table containing :

```
VideoID Views DeviceType

1       12    Desktop

1       30    Mobile

1       95    Tablette

...
```

I want to create a slicer names Views Ranges with ranges like below to filter videos by the sum of their views :

From 100 to 1000

From 1001 to 10000

...

VideoID 1 has a total 137 of views, so when I choose From 100 to 1000 in the filter it will be show.

This is what I tried :

```
Range =
VAR ranges =[Total Views]
 
RETURN
SWITCH(TRUE(),
ranges <= 100, "From 0 to 100",
ranges <= 10000, "From 100 to 10,000",
ranges <= 20000, "From 10,000 to 20,000",
....
)
```

But the filter is empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to fit the **Basic Category** of the **Static Segmentation** pattern. It's explained in full detail here:

https://www.daxpatterns.com/static-segmentation/

To summarize: I would add a DAX Calculated Column to your first table ("Views"?) to return the Key from a table of ranges.  You can then use that Key to establish a relationship to the table of ranges. With the relationship in place, you can use the table of ranges to filter in a Slicer, or categorize in any other visual.